# can't overwrite CGI program without restarting apache

Tags: linux, apache, cgi, fastcgi, kill

This is my code that I ended up compiling for fastcgi and apache using:

```
gcc ./fcgi.c -lfcgi -Wall -Wextra
```

I then copy a.out to document root, start apache and run a.out in the browser and things work as expected (as long as the 410 status code is taken out).

Now my issue is if I make changes to the program, I have to terminate apache and then the program with the killall command in linux. If I don't do it, then I get the message:

cp: cannot create regular file `/documentrootfolder/a.out': Text file busy

I added signal handling in my program in hopes that all I have to do is issue `killall a.out` then copy the file, but even that does not work.

What can I do to update the compiled program without restarting the apache server?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fcgi_stdio.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char ex='0';
void s(int s){ex='1';}

int main(){
  signal(SIGINT,s);
  signal(SIGTERM,s);
  while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0 && ex != '1'){
//          FCGI_printf("HTTP/1.1 410 Gone\r\n");
      FCGI_printf("Content-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n");
      FCGI_printf("<h1>Test</h1>\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I presume you hit the page from your browser after sending the signal to make the `FCGI_Accept()` unblock and notice the `ex`?

Comment: I only loaded the page from my browser once and according to the server log, the program starts up. Its just the program won't kill with `killall a.out`. What's strange is that I have better luck with using `kill -9 <pid of a.out>` to end the program but after that I try executing the program in the browser and I get internal server error and the logs show a timeout when starting the program.